Как правильно передать x-www-form-urlencoded в fetch&?
С помощью Postman формирую следующий запрос:

в результате олучаю coockies, для дальнейших запросов. Но когда в своем скрипте js использую следующий код:
    const formData = new URLSearchParams({
    'dispatch[auth.login]': '',
    user_login: creds.login,
    password: creds.password,
    return_url: 'https://baltikaonline.ru/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=9059',
    redirect_url: 'index.php?dispatch=auth.baltika_login_form'
});

const authData =  await fetch(
    `https://baltikaonline.ru/index.php`,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: formData
    })

Не получаю нужных cookies. Подозреваю, что неверно передаю тело запроса. Пробовал передавать formData.toString() - не помогает. Что делаю не так? Спасибо.

Вопрос в том, как вы пытаетесь получить куки

Да, забыл написать:
.then(response => {
const cookies = response.headers.get("set-cookie");
})

Заголовок Set-Cookie нельзя прочитать из JS. Большая красная плашка тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Надо во-первых при отсылке данных поставить credentials:
{
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: formData
    credentials: 'include', // возможно надо 'same-origin', а не 'include'
}

И получать ответ:
const response =  await fetch...


console.log(response.headers.get('set-cookie'));


Кстати, у Postman есть очень хорошая штука в виде получения кода текущего запроса на нужном языке программирования:




Большое спасибо за подробный ответ. Про код из Postman не знал. Но добавление credentials не помогло(оба варианта). В ответ получаю cookies, которые не проходят авторизацию.

Вопрос был про "как получить куки", про какую-то авторизацию речи не было и совсем не про это вопрос. Куки были получены. Значит ответ на вопрос правильный...... А что там с авторизацией - это уже другой вопрос, в котором надо разбираться

Проблема в том, что при любом запросе возвращаются куки, но при неверном запросе - куки не позволяют авторизоваться, а при верной конфигурации - те что нужны. Postman получает нужные куки, а код в js нет. Если взять куки из Postman и использовать в коде js для запросов к защищенным страницам - все работает.
